# aws-lambda-nodejs: How can I use callback function to return a value which I printed in aws-console?

Tags: node.js, callback, return-value, aws-lambda

This is the code running in an aws lambda function.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
            // TODO implement

          mqfunc1(func2);



};
var func2 = function(data) {
            console.log('got data: '+data);

};
var mqfunc1 = function(callback) {
        var myCallback = function(data) {
        console.log('got data: '+data);
        };

        var usingItNow = function(callback) {
        callback('get it?');
        };

};
```

Now I do get the the message which i want to print in the console. But I want to show the same message printed in the console using the callback function inside exports.handler.

I tried using callback function using various ways inside exports.handler but I am always getting null. I do understand that in a node js scripts all the function calls are asynchronous, so how do I return a value from any function and callback the same inside exports.handler, i.e. display the same in Execution result.

Comment: Can you add a sample output of what you are expecting.

Answer (score 26):

That was the old version of lambda i.e for Node.js runtime v0.10.42. The new AWS version callback has two arguments i.e for Node.js runtime v4.3 or v6.10

> callback(response_error, response_success)

```
module.exports.publisher = (event, context, callback) => 
{
   callback(response_error, response_success)
}
```

I tend to pass a status code, in case I want to use the result after my job is done:

```
const response_success = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'ok'
      }),
};

const response_error = {
    statusCode: 400,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'error'
    }),
};

if (error) {
   callback(response_error)
} else {
   callback(undefined, response_success)
}
```

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: I think you have a typo in your second last line of the code sample. You want to pass `response_success ` to the callback as second parameter instead of `response_error `

Comment: I'm getting---->>>  {
    "message": "Internal server error"
} It should be showing my custom message

Comment: This is the closest I've gotten so far to this working... But I would like to mention just for future readers: The behavior of this callback function is VERY finicky and often doesn't work at all. Idk why but AWS seems to have done a very bad job at this and it oftentimes gives an internal server error or returns an empty message.

Answer (score 6):

You should call the `callback` function itself — the one passed as an argument to `exports.handler`.

E.g.:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      mqfunc1(callback);
};

var mqfunc1 = function(callback) {
    callback({'result': 'success'});
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful for a newbie like me :)

Comment: bear in mind that the callback function's first argument is for errors, and second is for success